# Running an expression that will divide if meets criteria

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression

I'm trying to figure out on how to write an expression for a derived column. Basically what I want it to do is, if the data is greater than one, then divide by 100. If data is <=1, then do nothing and leave the current data as is. Expressions are pretty new to me, so wrapping my head around them is kind of tough.

Comment: [mycolumn] / case when [mycolumn]<=1 then 1 else 100 end

Comment: in SSIS expressions use an IIF function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conditional operator.

```
«boolean_expression» ? «when_true» : «when_false»
```

e.g.

```
[data] > 1 ? [data] /100 : [data]
```

Comment: Yep, that was what I needed. I  figured it out just before  I went to bed last night after it drove me utterly nuts. Once I figured out how to use the type cast I was able to get it just right. Heres what my final wound up being that worked. (DT_WSTR,255)[Data Conversion].[Percentage Off] >= "1" ? (DT_CY)[Data Conversion].[Percentage Off] / 100 : [Data Conversion].[Percentage Off]